# What does a continuation return in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations, delimited-continuations

I came across something that I can not understand.

```
#lang scheme

(define cc #f)

(define (val!)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (k)
     (set! cc k)
     0)))

(* 10 (val!))

(cc 100)
```

So far so good; the continuation of `(* 10 [])` is stored in `cc` and if we call `(cc 100)` we see `1000` in the REPL as expected.

But the next thing I tried was to define a variable to be the result of running the continuation:

```
(define x (cc 20))
```

I see `200` as a result in the REPL, but `x` does not get defined.

Does the continuation stored in `cc` include its returning so that the call to `define` never returns and instead the evaluation is the result of `(* 10 val)`? What is going on?

Comment: If you want continuations to return values, you should use composable continuations, by setting up a prompt and using `call-with-composable-continuation`.

Answer (score 3):

#### What's going on?

There are two types of continuations.

A continuation produced by [`call/cc`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-current-continuation%29%29) never returns a value to its caller. See [Will Ness's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498782/what-does-a-continuation-return-in-scheme/46506359#46506359) for more on that.

But the continuations produced by [`call-with-composable-continuation`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._call-with-composable-continuation))) are *composable* continuations, which do return values.

#### The solution

If you want a continuation to return a value to its caller, you should use a composable continuation, by setting up a prompt and using [`call-with-composable-continuation`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._call-with-composable-continuation))).

You can define a kind of prompt:

```
(define my-prompt
  (make-continuation-prompt-tag 'my-prompt))
```

And use the prompt in [`call-with-composable-continuation`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._call-with-composable-continuation))) to specify that you only want to capture the continuation starting from the prompt.

```
(define cc #f)

(define (val!)
  (call-with-composable-continuation
   (lambda (k)
     (set! cc k)
     0)
   my-prompt))
```

Then you just have to put the prompt wherever you want the continuation to start before you call `val!` to save it.

```
;; the prompt specifies that it's `(* 10 [])`, and not something larger
(call-with-continuation-prompt
 (λ () (* 10 (val!)))
 my-prompt)
```

Then, since this continuation has a clear "end" defined by the prompt, it can return a value when it reaches that end.

```
(define x (cc 20))
; defines x as 200
```

See also: [What exactly is a "continuation prompt?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838344/what-exactly-is-a-continuation-prompt)

Answer (score 3):

It returns nothing, because it does not return. `(cc 20)`, just as `(cc 100)`, does *not* return a value to its caller. `cc` is not a function, it is a continuation - it remembers *where to* return / *"feed"*  its value, by itself.

```
(define x (cc 20))
```

means, approximately, in pseudocode,

```
(let ([val (cc 20)])
  (primitive-define-top-level-var! "x" val))
```

but `(cc 20)` bypasses the setting of `val` and using it to define `x`, and returns directly to the top level, as was done by the original captured continuation.

> Does the continuation stored in `cc` include its returning [*"destination"* -- wn] so that the call to `define` never returns and instead the evaluation is the result of `(* 10 val)`?

Yes.

> What is going on?

Exactly that.

---

*edit:*

Loading the following in DrRacket,

```
#lang scheme

(define cc #f)
(define (val!)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (k)
     (set! cc k)
     0)))
(* 10 (val!))
(cc 100)
(display "Good!\n")
(define x (cc 20))
(display "Shucks!\n")
```

I even get an error message explaining what is going on:

> Language: scheme, with debugging; memory limit: 128 MB.
>   0
>   1000
>   Good!
>   200
>   *define-values: skipped variable definition;
>
>      cannot continue without defining variable
>
>        variable: x
>
>        in module: 'anonymous-module*
>   >

Comment: And of course if you would wrap the code in `let` so you have no continuation barrier between the expressions you'll see that it becomes an infinite loop doing `(* 10 20)`

Comment: @Sylwester I couldn't understand your comment. Could you show the full code that you mention?  Mine was just a pseudocode.

Comment: Just wrap the whole top level expressions in a `(let () ...)` and you never get "Good!\n" output since the previous line jumps back to `(* 10 100)` every time. The behaviour with `define` is not specified in R5RS, which is what PLTs `#lang scheme` is supposed to follow.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Of course, that "makes sense", because `let` has an implicit `begin`.

Comment: @Sylwester `#lang scheme` is badly named; it does not follow any Scheme standard. It is a holdover from the era of PLT Scheme, and it is essentially `#lang racket`. Only `#lang r5rs` follows R5RS.

Comment: @AlexisKing I couldn't even find a documentation for it.

Comment: @AlexisKing It's the same as `#lang racket` before they made the pairs immutable. It conforms to R5RS with lots of incompatible extra bindings, just like any R5RS would do. Will: The split was announced with [this blogpost](https://racket-lang.org/new-name.html) and [here is the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scheme/index.html?q=scheme%2Fbase)

Comment: @Sylwester That’s not true; pairs in `#lang scheme` have been immutable ever since they made the pairs immutable. There is no reason to use `#lang scheme`. It is a legacy language for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: @AlexisKing That's unfortunate for the "for backwards compatibility" part. I guess that's what broke Grahams Arc a while back.

Comment: @Sylwester The purpose was to make old code written in `#lang scheme` work with new code written in `#lang racket`, so the process of porting to `#lang racket` could be more incremental instead of needing to be all-at-once. There’s still a fair number of modules in Racket itself written in `#lang scheme`, I believe. People usually convert them whenever they need to change them for some reason or another.